# SQL query in Access to count records on the subset of of non-primary fields

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Suppose I have the table T with the following fields:

T(**F1**, **F2**, F3, F4, F5)

where combination of F1 & F2 forms a **primary key** for this table.

What would be the Access SQL query to select the following:
T(F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, *F4_F5_Count*)

where *F4_F5_Count* is a count of duplicates of the combination of fields F4 and F5 **only** (i.e. not all fields that are being selected but only last two).?

Comment: please provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery for this:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t as t2 where t2.f4 = f.f4 and t2.f5 = f.f5
      ) as fr_f5_cnt
from t;
```

Or, use `join` with an aggregation:

```
select t.*, tt.f4_f5_count
from t join
     (select f4, f5, count(*) as f4_f5_count
      from t
      group by f4, f5
     ) tt
    on t2.f4 = f.f4 and t2.f5 = f.f5;
```

EDIT:

You would use the second method and add:

```
where f4_f5_count = 1
```

Comment: How would I write if on top of this I want to apply HAVING clause in order to filter out for records having f4_f5_count=1?